# v8 constructors

Tags: v8

I am studying v8 source code and can't seem to find where all the basic constructors like Array, Object or String are defined.

There is

```
InstallFunctions($Object.prototype, DONT_ENUM, $Array(
```

in *v8natives.js* and

```
var $Object = global.Object;
```

in *runtime.js*, but where `global.Object` is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are coming from the bootstrapper. For example [Object](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/bootstrapper.cc#L1140) and [Array](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/bootstrapper.cc#L1282).